# CodeBlocks linker issue with MySQL on Windows 8.1

Tags: mysql, c, windows, codeblocks, linker-errors

I am trying to connect to MySQL server using C in the CodeBlocks 13.12 IDE on Windows 8.1. Following are my build options.
[image]

[image]

My code is as follows.

```
#ifdef WIN32
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <winsock.h>
  #pragma warning (disable: 4514 4786)
  #pragma warning( push, 3 )
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#ifndef WIN32
  #include <unistd.h>
#endif
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  MYSQL mysql;

  if(mysql_init(&mysql)==NULL){
        printf("\nFailed to initate MySQL connection");
        exit(1);
    }
  /*now you can call any MySQL API function you like*/
if(!mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"localhost","user","password","molecules",0,NULL,0)){
     printf( "Failed to connect to MySQL: Error: %s\n",
mysql_error(&mysql));
     exit(1);
   }
printf("Logged on to database sucessfully");
mysql_close(&mysql);
  }
```

I am getting the following errors.

[image]

Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 3):

Codeblocks does not like MySQL for some reason. Im assuming you have the MySQL C connector? If not you can get it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/)

From inside the MySQL C Connector directory, copy the full contents of the folder named Include, then go into your MinGW directory and paste the contents into the Include folder of MinGW.

Download [this](https://mega.nz/#!NsMnHJrb!E1njKLpSy-ZsUp_DMqv3SrWMRADxnVy9ypAB0sYUkEE) Zip folder which contains libmysql.a and libmysql.dll. Unzip and copy libmysql.a into the lib folder in MingGW. Copy the libmysql.dll into the Windows System32 and SysWOW64 folders.

Finally in Codeblocks, in Compiler settings/Linker settings/Other linker options - type " -lmysql " without quotes.

Not tested on windows 8.1, works on windows 7.

You have a lot of unnecessary code to just test the connection.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  MYSQL *conn = mysql_init(NULL);

  if (!(mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "username", "password", "database", 0, NULL, 0)))
  {
      printf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
      mysql_close(conn);
      exit(1);
  }
  printf ("Connection Succesful");
  mysql_close(conn);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've got this: 
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\..\..\..\crt2.o|| undefined reference to `_CRT_fenv'|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\..\..\..\crt2.o|| undefined reference to `_setargv'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|